# Keep Alive and Multiple SSO Domino HTTP configuration

Tags: xpages, keep-alive

I have some problem in this specific scenario:

If my XPages application

If I have my Domino HTTP configure with Single server setting the Ext.lib Keep-Alive control work well...and my session don't expire.

But I I use Domino HTTP configured with Multiple SSO (LPTAtoken) with Firebug I see the Ext.lib Keep-Alive control work well (I see the PING request) but I don't know because my session expire.

Have someone any suggest for me?

Tnx you

p.s. my release in 9 social on linux 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of key did you use when you created the LTPA token?

When using WebSphere LTPA keys, a token is assigned and it will expire when the time specified in the field Expiration (minutes) elapses, no matter whether you are actively using your application or not.

When examining the documentation for products that use WebSphere server (Sametime, Connections) I found that IBM suggests to set Expiration time to a long interval (such as 600) minutes to minimize the risk of users being logged out in the middle of a working day. I admit that this does not sound like a good suggestion security-wise.

I assume it is the same when using Domino LTPA keys, with the added option of being able to specify Idle Session Timeout.

So, you can either increase the token expiration interval (depending on your requirements this could be an easy fix) or go with Stephan's suggestion. I don't know how to code his approach, but if I find a solution, I'll update this answer.

Comment: yes this is my solution...I have set the expire to 600minutes and Idle timeout to 30 minute. So Keep Alive work with Idle Timeout

Answer (score 2):

In a single server setting the server tracks the validity of the cookie. So whenever you hit the server it is updated. In a multi server environment you get a new cookie before expiry. So you need to process the incoming cookie to replace the predecessor. Easiest way using a regular page and an iframe

Comment: tnx you @stwilles, but How can I realize that? Have you sample of code?

Comment: Ciao Daniele, the lazy way (which I would pick) is to have an iframe src="..." that points to a classic page in Domino. in its HTTP header you use the META tag to reload that page every 5 minutes. Since it is a regular page load, the cookie gets updated - no actual code required. All HTML